# Javascript onClick confirm not firing

Tags: javascript, html

I've placed an onClick goconfirm on a hyperlink per below:

```
<a href="http://google.com" onclick="goConfirm('This link is to an external site. You are now 
leaving mysite.,'href=http://google.com');' target="_blank">Online Account Opening</a>
```

How do I ensure the confirmation Javascript message fires before sending the user to the new site?

Thanks much for your help and guidance.

Comment: Can you show the code in `goConfirm`?

Comment: You're missing a `'` at the end of your first argument. Additionally, you have a `'` at the end of the attribute value instead of a `"`, which was used to start the value.

Comment: Check the console, please!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not preventing the default action in any way. Try this instead:

```
<a href="..." onclick="return confirm('This link is... ');">...</a>
```

Or if `goConfirm` is actually a function of yours, you should add `return false;` to the end of the onclick.

Also fix the mismatched quotes ;)

Answer (score 2):

I guess it was a typo. Try this instead:

```
<a href="http://google.com" onclick="goConfirm('This link is to an external site. You are now leaving mysite.','href=http://google.com');return false;" target="_blank">Online Account Opening</a>
```

I also added a `return false` at the end to ensure the current web page won't be redirected.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the code to open the new page from the anchor tag to the JS function so that it waits till you confirm.

```
<script>
function goConfirm(message, url) {
  var choice = confirm(message);
  if (choice) {
    window.open(url, "_blank");
  }
}
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="goConfirm('This link is to an external site. You are now leaving mysite.,\'href=http://google.com\'', 'http://google.com');">Online Account Opening</a>
```

Fiddle at - http://jsfiddle.net/poonia/2bYKV/

Answer (score 0):

use `<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return confirm('This link is... ');">...</a>` to avoid any change in url